# Start bootloader from firmware

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I wish to be able to start the bootloader directly from the code without having to have a pin high and reset the microcontroller to access it. The idea below is that the bootloader binary is stored in a char array. When Start_BootLoader() is called, the bootloader is copied into SRAM and executed.

However, the code copies into RAM but when it attempts to execute the code at the location I have copied it to, it does nothing.

The micro. is an Energy Micro EFM32380f1024. The code below that I am using is based on Energy Micro's application note AN0042.

```
void Start_Bootloader(void)
{
  /* Diable interrupts */
  INT_Disable();

  __set_MSP( ( 0x20000000 + sizeof( bootloader ) + 0x400 ) & 0xFFFFFFF0 );

  /* Load the entire bootloader into SRAM. */

  memcpy( (void*)0x20000000, bootloader, sizeof( bootloader ) );

  /* Start executing the bootloader. */

  BOOT_jump( *(uint32_t*)0x20000000, *(uint32_t*)0x20000004 );
}
```

Comment: I don't know this particular device, but a quick Internet search seems to indicate an ARM chip?

You have copied code around. Does `BOOT_jump()`flushes the instruction cache?

Comment: It's not clear to me that the EM bootloader is position independent. I didn't see anything in the app note and the IAR project files that are distributed with the app note do not build it as position independent. So I guess I would wonder what makes you think it should run when copied into a new memory location.

Comment: you have verified that the bootloader data is actually there (in non-volatile storage) and it is not just copying random data from ram to ram?

Comment: and you have disabled the i and d caches?

Comment: EFM32GG has neither I nor D cache. See Cortex M3 Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code ships with ROM and RAM linker settings - but only the RAM version will likely work in your case. Try to read the second word (32 Bit little endian) from your binary - it should point to an odd address in the 0x20000000 range, as it is the new PC value.

Comment: That one: `*(uint32_t*)0x20000004` after `memcpy()`.